# Initiating Navigational Controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have the following code implemented in app delegate didFinishLaunchWithOptions

```
NotificationsViewController *viewController = [[NotificationsViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                        initWithRootViewController:viewController];

_window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
_window.rootViewController = nav;
[_window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

When it gets to the last line of code, compiler tells me:

```
Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
```

What am I doing wrong? didn't I set the window.rootviewController to nag?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create the uiwondow. 
Remove all the code that allocs and inits _window 
Now 
Try this: self.window.rootViewController = nav;